# Set Video src with string from database

Tags: asp.net, video

Hello and thanks for reading this.

I'm trying to show a video inside a repeater if there is a "link/string" inside the database field.

As you can see here I have tried different ways but nothing seems to work.

```
<%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "VideoID", "~/QuestionContent/Video/{0}") != null) ? "<iframe id='Video' width='240' height='200' src='" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "VideoID", "~/QuestionContent/Video/{0}") + "' allowfullscreen></iframe>" : "" %>
<video width="240" src='<%# DataBinder.Eval("VideoID", "~/QuestionContent/Video/{0}") %>' controls="controls"  />
```

To explain some of the parts of my code: The **"VideoID"** is the column name inside the database and that contains the video name plus type ( like : Movie.Mp4 ) / The **"~/QuestionContent/Video/"** is the location of where the movie is stored on my server.

Is there anyway to solve this so I can display a video if the video name exist inside the database.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<video width="240" src='<%# ResolveUrl("~/QuestionContent/Video/" + Eval("VideoID") )  %>' controls="controls" runat="server" visible=<%# (Eval("VideoID") != null) %> />
```